# How would I echo users who haven't confirmed their email

Tags: php

I know how to echo the number of users that have activated their email but it got a bit tricky when I wanted to echo the number of unverified users.

My register system assigns a key in the `active` column in the `members` table. If the user activates their email it goes from a random md5 string to 'Yes'

ex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyxHc.jpg

Anyways... this is what I got so far:

```
$result3 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `active` = 'Yes'");
$unverified_users = mysqli_num_rows($result3);
```

I just dunno how to echo the number of unverified users instead of the verified users.

Any help is appreciated btw I'm a noob to PHP so go easy on me :P

Comment: Am I missing something? `WHERE active != 'Yes'`

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_num_rows` to count things, use `SELECT COUNT(*)` to do it in the database, so you don't have to return all the rows to the client.

Comment: @Barmar `WHERE active != 'Yes'` seemed to work thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

`$result3 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE active != 'Yes'");
$unverified_users = mysqli_num_rows($result3);`

I didn't know that != meant not equal to... my bad lol

Thanks to @Barmar

Comment: That's the same as your original query.

Comment: use count(*) instead, it should be faster, because the db doesn't have to prepare a number of results equal to the number of matching rows, but only prepare 1 result, the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

use count(*).

`$unverified_users=$db->query("SELECT count(*) FROM members WHERE active != 'Yes'")->fetch_array()[0];`

this should be faster than `SELECT *` because now the db only has to prepare 1 result, the number of matches, instead of preparing a number of results equal to the number of matches.